# Sum the total balance for people between two ages

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to calculate the total balance of people/clients between two ages that have an account within a bank. I can get it to display the list of people that fall under the requirement.

These are the constructors

```
    type NI = Int
    type Age = Int
    type Balance = Int
    type Person = (NI, Age, Balance)
    type Bank = [Person]
```

This is the Bank

```
    rbs :: Bank
    rbs = [ (1, 73, 1000)
        , (2, 18, -50)
        , (3, 60, 190)
        , (4, 26, 300)
        , (5, 24, 456)
        , (6, 32, 7500)
        , (7, 41, -46)
        , (8, 59, -850)
        , (9, 44, 348)
        , (10, 66, -1000)
        , (11, 37, 20000)
        , (12, 29, -245)
        , (13, 55, 3090)
        ]
```

And this is my code to recursively check the bank

```
        equityA' :: Bank -> (Int, Int) -> Bank
        equityA' ((n,a,b):xs) (0,0) = error "No ages were selected"
        equityA' [] (x,y) = []
        equityA' ((n,a,b):xs) (f, s) = if  (f <= a) && (s >= a) then  (n,a,b) : equityA' xs (f, s) 
                                       else equityA' xs (f, s)
```

If I run equityA' rbs (40,50) the output will be [(7,41,-46),(9,44,348)]

What i'm struggling to do is to is print out the total balance of those people. I have some code down but am stuck at the actual calculation part.

The code for to check the total.

```
    equityAge :: Bank -> (Int, Int) -> Int              
    equityAge ((n,a,b):xs) (0,0) = error "No ages were selected"
    equityAge [] (x,y) = 0
    equityAge ((n,a,b):xs) (f, s) =
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You can get a list with only the third element of each tuple by `map (\(_,_,b) -> b) list`. Does that help?

Comment: I was trying to use map to get the total from the entire list of tuples, however looking at the structure of the map you posted I finally managed to get it working. Thanks

Comment: The real answer probably goes along the lines of: `data Person = Person { ni :: Int, age :: Int, balance :: Int }`. Then you could `map balance` on a `Bank`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple if you use [list comprehensions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing#List_comprehensions):

```
equityAge :: Bank -> (Int,Int) -> Int
equityAge _ (0,0) = error "No ages were selected"
equityAge [] (x,y) = 0
equityAge x (f,s) = sum [ b | (n,a,b) <-x, f <= a, a <= s]
```

Other than that you can apply [Sarah's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333607/sum-the-total-balance-for-people-between-two-ages/13333865#comment18193528_13333607) and use `map` and `sum` on your original function:

```
equityAge :: Bank -> (Int,Int) -> Int
equityAge _ (0,0) = error "No ages were selected"
equityAge [] (x,y) = 0
equityAge x (f,s) = sum (map(\(_,_,b) -> b) (equityA' x (f,s)))
```

Comment: I struggle a little bit with list comprehension, however I managed to get it working with what Sarah had posted and now its pretty much identical to your second answer. Thank you

Comment: @Zantengetsu: `[ b | (n,a,b) <-x, f <= a, a <= s]` roughly means *take all `b` which are in a tuple `(n,a,b)` in the list `x`, where `a` is greater or equal to `f` and smaller or equal to `s`*. If you know the [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) it gets much easier.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look through it to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main things I would recommend here: (a) use **record types** instead of tuples; (b) use **standard utility functions** to work with lists and other standard types; (c) write **auxiliary functions** to help keep all of you functions short and readable.

On the first recommendation:

```
data Person = Person { ni :: NI, age :: Age, balance :: Balance } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now you don't have to do any of that tuple pattern matching just to get a person's age; this record type declaration gets you functions `age :: Person -> Age` and `balance :: Person -> Balance` for free.

Example of the third recommendation: here is a function to calculate whether a `Person` is between two ages:

```
betweenAges :: Age -> Age -> Person -> Bool
betweenAges lo hi person = lo <= age person && age person <= hi
```

Now, using that auxiliary function and the standard `filter` function, you can get all the persons between two ages like this:

```
filter (betweenAges 18 27) rbs
```

To get the balance of a list of `Person`s you can just use the standard `sum` and `map` functions:

```
sum (map balance somePersons)
```

So the complete solution would be something like this:

```
-- Note how much easier to read this is when you use sum, map, filter 
-- and betweenAges!
equityAge :: Age -> Age -> Bank -> Balance
equityAge lo hi bank = sum (map balance (filter (betweenAges lo hi) bank))
    -- This could be its own top-level function if you're going to reuse it
    -- somewhere else, but here I'm putting it in a where declaration assuming
    -- that it's a throwaway.
    where betweenAges lo hi person = lo <= age person && age person <= hi
```

As a general rule, laboring away to figure out how to solve the issue you're tackling is not productive.  The more productive strategy, I believe, is the following: (a) learn to solve your problems in terms of the functions in the basic libraries like `Prelude`, `Data.List` and `Data.Maybe`; (b) learn how to write those utility functions on your own.  Why this way?  Because (a) teaches you how to break problems down into small, reusable pieces, and (b) teaches you to understand what's going on from the bottom to the top in these programs.