# List the National Insurance numbers that do not have an account

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to list a bunch of numbers that do not belong to specific banks.

Here is my code

Types

```
     type NI = Int
     type Age = Int
     type Balance = Int
     type Person = (NI, Age, Balance)
     type Bank = [Person]
     type Market = [Bank]
     type Pop = [NI]
```

Banks

```
     rbs :: Bank
     rbs = [ (1, 73, 1000)
         , (2, 18, -50)
         , (3, 60, 190)
         , (4, 26, 300)
         , (5, 24, 456)
         , (6, 32, 7500)
         , (7, 41, -46)
         , (8, 59, -850)
         , (9, 44, 348)
         , (10, 66, -1000)

     clyde :: Bank
     clyde = [(1, 73, 240)
           , (2, 18, -70)
           , (23, 30, 800)
           , (14, 16, 30)
           , (5, 24, 800)
           , (19, 81, 750)
           , (17, 49, 946)
           , (20, 59, -850)
           , (29, 24, -348)
           , (30, 76, -100)

    sco :: Pop
    sco = [1..20]
```

And this is my code to check if the NI is not in the Bank

```
    bankFree :: Pop -> Market -> Pop
    bankFree [] x = []
    bankFree x [] = error "No Banks selected"
    bankFree x [[]] = []
    bankFree (x:xs) [[],((n,a,b):ys)] = if x == n then bankFree (xs) [[],ys]
                                else x : bankFree xs [[],ys]
    bankFree x [[],[]] = []
    bankFree (x:xs) (((n,a,b):ys):zs) = if x == n then bankFree (xs) ((ys):zs)
                                else if x /= n then x : bankFree xs ((ys):zs)
                                else bankFree (xs) zs
```

If I run bankFree sco [rbs,clyde] what should show is [11,12,13,15,16,18,20] however what comes up is [2..20]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong and how to proceed, so any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: By the way, are "National Insurance number"s numbers?

Comment: @pigworker In this case they are meant to be Int's so NI = 1, NI = 2 and so on.

Comment: @pigworker: At least according to Neil and the coursework he sent out.

Comment: As far as a homework exercise is concerned they might as well be numbers, so Neil's choice is perfectly reasonable. And you've shown your hand.

Comment: @pigworker: Yeah, I have no problem with them being Int's, it makes it a little bit easier searching for numbers instead of taking a whole String, less to memorize anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, as I suggested in [my answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336221/1094403), the reason you're having so much difficulty with this is that you're not effectively breaking the problems down into smaller pieces, and you're not helping yourself to the standard utility functions to manage the lists.  You're trying to bite off too large of a piece at a time, and that makes it hard to solve.

So you want to break your problem down into subparts that are easy to solve on their own, then combine these into the big solution to the big problem:

```
import Data.List (any)

type Market = [Bank]
type Bank = [Person]
data Person = Person { ni :: NI, age :: Age, balance :: Balance } 
    deriving (Eq, Show)

bankFree :: Pop -> Market -> Pop
bankFree pop banks = filter checkBanks pop
    where checkBanks n = not (any (bankHasNI n banks))

bankHasNI :: NI -> Bank -> Bool
bankHasNI n bank = any (\person -> ni person == n) bank
```

Required reading:

- [`Data.List`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html)

Comment: Yeah I can see what your saying and I hadn't read your previous post but after checking that I managed to tidy up my code and get it to do what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Split it into smaller problems.  Also, use higher-order functions instead of manual recursion to make your algorithm easier to understand:

```
inBank :: NI -> Bank -> Bool
ni `inBank` bank = any (\(ni', _, _) -> ni' == ni) bank

inMarket :: NI -> Market -> Bool
ni `inMarket` market = any (ni `inBank`) market

bankless :: Pop -> Market -> Pop
bankless pop market = filter (not . (`inMarket` market)) pop
```

If you test it out, you get:

```
>>> bankless sco [rbs, clyde]
[11,12,13,15,16,18]
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is homework, so just solving the problem for you is not ok, but here are some hints:

- It helps to formalize what your function should do as a question: "Given this population and given these lists of bank customers, who of them does NOT have an account?"
- Given the above problem formulation, it becomes natural to think of the `bankFree` function as a filter. Here are some people, *for each* person, only keep it if it does not have a bank account.

Filtering a list can be implemented in lots of different ways, the easiest for a beginner is probably to use a list comprehension:

```
bankFree :: Pop -> Market -> Pop
bankFree pop market = [p | p <- pop, not (isBankCustomer market p)]
```

Should be read as: *return all persons in Pop that are not bank customers*. The definition for `isBankCustomer` should be:

```
isBankCustomer :: NI -> Market -> Bool   
isBankCustomer ni market = ?
```

What you want to do here is to somehow check if ni is present in any of the banks lists of customers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew that bankFree was supposed to filter the Market for those with no accounts, however while working through it I was finding myself bogged down with so much code that I didn't know what was doing what. I've since realized that I have to research higher-order functions and list comprehension in order to get a better understanding of haskell and to make my life easier.